# Vagrant w/VirtualBox and Multiple Network Interfaces

Tags: networking, centos, virtual-machines, vagrant

What's the right way to configure multiple network interfaces with Vagrant? Here's the simple Vagrant file I'm testing with:

.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    # vb.gui = true
    vb.memory = 512
    vb.cpus = 1
  end

  config.vm.define "consumer" do |c|
    c.vm.box = "vagrant-centos6.2-x64"
    c.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.100.12"
    c.vm.network :private_network, ip: "172.16.100.12"
    c.vm.hostname = "consumer.XXXXXX.XXX"
  end
end
```

.

This behaves inconsistently. The 2 private_network interfaces always come up as eth1 and eth2 with distinct MAC's but sometimes both interfaces are assigned the same IP, sometimes neither is assigned an IP address, and sometimes it works correctly.

I'm using CentOS 6 on both the desktop and virtual image and VirtualBox 4.1. Is there a better way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Upgrade your virtualbox version as the network drivers have been greatly improved since 4.1

Comment: Upgraded to 4.3. Fixed. My thanks to you both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That configuration looks perfectly valid. Maybe it's the oldish VirtualBox version. Could you try upgrading it to the latest 4.2.x or 4.3.y?

Otherwise, a gist/pastebin of full `--debug` log of an incorrect Vagrant invocation and the contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth*` could help.